# I've been stuck on this issue for days Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to complete a project for class and after asking some of my peers who couldn't figure out the problem I'd like to ask for help.

I've had a read of some of the similar questions that have been asked but I haven't been able to figure out the problem just using those sources.

```
private void products_lstValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                          
    //whenever this event is triggered update the selected product to be whichever one is highlighted in the list
    //get the selected Value from the list - returned as an OBJECT
    Object selectedObject = (Object)products_lst.getSelectedValue();

    //cast the object to an animal and set as selectedAnimal value
    selectedProduct = (Product)selectedObject;

    updateQuantity();
    }                                         

    private void updateQuantity()
    {
        int stockLevel =selectedProduct.getStockLevel();

        Order latest = currentCustomer.findLatestOrder();

        for(Map.Entry<Integer, OrderLine> oEntry : latest.getOrderLines().entrySet())
        {
            if(oEntry.getValue().getProduct().getProductId() == selectedProduct.getProductId())
            {
                stockLevel-=oEntry.getValue().getQuantity();
            }

        }

        if(selectedProduct != null)
        {
            quantity_cmb.removeAllItems();

            for(int i = 1; i<=stockLevel;i++)
            {
                quantity_cmb.addItem(""+i);
            }
        }
   }
```

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at Views.ViewProducts.updateQuantity(ViewProducts.java:233)
>       at Views.ViewProducts.products_lstValueChanged(ViewProducts.java:228)

Comment: Which line pop up NPE?  By the way, such problem should be debugged easily..

Comment: int stockLevel =selectedProduct.getStockLevel();

And

 updateQuantity();

Comment: This means `Object selectedObject = (Object)products_lst.getSelectedValue();`  get nothing.. you need check your `products_lst` by debugging.

Comment: `products_lst.getSelectedValue()` returns null if nothing is selected in the list.  You need to account for that in your code.

Answer (score 0):

So looking at the exception trace, the exception appears to happen five (233-228) lines after the call to `products_lstValueChanged` in `updateQuantity`.

That line is:

```
    int stockLevel =selectedProduct.getStockLevel();
```

So `selectedProduct` is `null`. This implies `products_lst.getSelectedValue()` returned `null`.

So it seems that this code was called when no item was selected. Possibly it had just been deselected. You need to handle that case.